# Select all parents which has same classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to select all parents which has same class using jQuery

now i can select only one element but i want to select all parent elements

```
<div class="text">
 <div class="text">
  <div class="text">
   <div class="text">
    <div class="text">
     <div class="text-3">
      hi
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

in this i need to select the parent elements of `.text-3` which has `text` as a classname

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You can try `$('.text-3').parents('.text')`

Comment: Select ALL the parents with class `text` ? Quite rare to nest so many class with same name.

Comment: difficult to choose the correct answer as all are same ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**:

> Description: Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$('.text-3').parents('.text')
```

to iterate over each element, use:

```
$('.text-3').parents('.text').each(function(){
   //code here
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPCmZ/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**:

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
var parents = $('.text-3').parents('.text')
```

or **[has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)**:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant
>   that matches the selector or DOM element.

```
var parents = $('.text').has('.text-3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$('.text-3').parents('.text')
```

Example from the linked site:

> Find all parent elements of each b.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>parents demo</title>
  <style>
  b, span, p, html body {
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
  strong {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <p>
    <span>
      <b>My parents are: </b>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
var parentEls = $( "b" ).parents()
  .map(function() {
    return this.tagName;
  })
  .get()
  .join( ", " );
$( "b" ).append( "<strong>" + parentEls + "</strong>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> My parents are: SPAN, P, DIV, BODY, HTML